# Cancellation in the linear regression hat matrix

Tags: matrices

While studying linear regression, I've been introduced to the so-called hat matrix: $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.

Why doesn't it reduce to $I$?

$H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T = X(X^{-1}(X^T)^{-1})X^T = XX^{-1}X^{-T}X^T = II = I$

Am I incorrectly distributing the inverse of $(X^TX)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$ only if both $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices. Since $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, where $n$ is the number of observations, and $p$ the dimension of each observation, is it possible for $X$ be invertible?

Comment: I see, it's only possible if X happens to be invertible.

Comment: Yes, and in the standard theory we always take $n>p$, so $X$ is not a square matrix and is therefore never invertible